# How to use nested Fn:Join within StringEquals operator in CFT for a role?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks, identity-management

I am trying to create a role using CFT. That should look like:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "IAM role that trusts the EKS OIDC provider and AWSLoadBalancerControllerIAMPolicy",
    "Parameters": {
        "OIDCProviderURL":
        {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "OIDC provider URL that you have created.",
            "Default": ""
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "EKSOIDCALBTrustRole": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "Properties": {
                "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "Federated": 
                                [
                                    {
                                        "Fn::Join": [
                                            "/",
                                            [
                                                "arn:aws:iam::",
                                                {
                                                    "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
                                                },
                                                ":oidc-provider",
                                                {
                                                    "Ref":"OIDCProviderURL"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },  
                            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
                            "Condition": {
                                "StringEquals": {
                                    "oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/123AAAX9DD757X9867Y2466IO6R97046:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com",
                                    "oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/123AAAX9DD757X9867Y2466IO6R97046:sub": "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:aws-load-balancer-controller"                   
                                }
                            }
                        }   
                    ]   
                },
                "RoleName": "EKS-OIDC-ALB-TrustRole",
                "ManagedPolicyArns": [
                    {
                        "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:policy/AWSLoadBalancerControllerIAMPolicy"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "EKSOIDCALBTrustRoleArn": {
            "Value": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "EKSOIDCALBTrustRole",
                    "Arn"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now my problem is, I want to make the StringEquals portion dynamic using OIDCProviderURL parameter. How can I do that, so that I do not have to hardcode the OIDC provider URL in the CFT?

I have tried:

```
"Condition": {
    "Fn::And": [
        {
            "StringEquals": {
                "Fn:Join": [
                    ": ",
                    [
                        {
                            "Fn:Join": [
                                ":",
                                [
                                    {
                                        "Ref":"OIDCProviderURL"
                                    },
                                    "aud"
                                ]
                            ]
                        },
                        "sts.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                ]
            }  
        },  
        {
            "StringEquals": {
                "Fn:Join": [
                    ": ",
                    [
                        {
                            "Fn:Join": [
                                ":",
                                [
                                    {
                                        "Ref":"OIDCProviderURL"
                                    },
                                    "sub"
                                ]
                            ]
                        },
                        "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:aws-load-balancer-controller"
                    ]
                ]
            } 
        }  
    ] 
}
```

But when I upload this to AWS, it gives me an error saying:
[image]